# Universal Windows Platform(UWP) Development

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, xaml, win-universal-app

I want to make a windows app which can run on any windows os and any windows device.

My questions are following.

1. Is windows 8 universal app can support on windows 10  and its higer version of os ?
2. Is windows 10 universal app can run on windows 8  and all windows operating system ?
3. which  way is feasible for creating windows app as per my requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer:

1) Yes

2) No

3) Linking shared code files in Visual Studio

Complex answer:

1) Windows Store app for Windows 8 runs on Windows 10, but it is incompatible on UI level. Windows 8 app must support split view, settings is accessible vie charm bar and back button must be present in XAML. Windows 10 app must be responsive, settings must be present in XAML, but Windows 10 provides back button.

2) All Windows operating systems since which version? Windows (10) Universal App can run on Windows 10 only.

3) You can share code files with ViewModels and Models, but UI must be written separately for every platform you target.

Comment: I want to create application which can support Window 8.1 and family and Windows 10 and family (Desktop, Mobile, Tablate and XBOX(if possible)). Can you please suggest me which Visual Studio version I should use?

Comment: Definitely Visual Studio 2015. Create a Shared project (Installed > Templates > Visual C#) and then 3 projects for Universal Windows, Universal Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone. Items in the Shared project are included in all 3 specific projects.

Comment: I mean I want to create single project which can have 1 UI and 1 Shared code and it should support for windows and windows phone of windows 8.1 and windows 10. Is it possible? If not, is it possible 3 UI for all 3 (Desktop, Tablate and Phone) and 1 shared Code file?

Comment: Only one single project is not possible becase Windows 8.1 use different AppManifest than Windows Phone 8.1. You must have 3 projects and 1 shared project. However the shared project can contain 90 % of your code. You don't have to necessarily create a special UI for Windows 10. Windows 8.1 app could be sufficient.

Comment: for creating a windows universal app  ,should i require a windows 10 updation or not ? my current operating system is windows 8.1.

Comment: Actually i am using visual studio 2015 and windows 8.1 ,while creating a windows universal app  xaml view is not shown means xaml designer view is not loaded so how can i see my xaml design view before emulator.

Comment: It is not possible. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn975273.aspx?Wt.mc_id=DX_MVP5000527

Comment: @VaclavDajvych Thank you so much. I got all most. Do I require specific Windows 10 operating system(Ex. Professional) or anyone will support?

Comment: Even Home edition should be ok.

Comment: @VaclavDajvych Which version of visual studio Do i require for developing a Universal Windows Platform(UWP) APP ?